# asp.net (4.x) and quartz.net (3.0.7.0) quartz_jobs.xml sheduling in Global.asax Application_Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz.net, global-asax

All was fine for my small home use only project running under iis 8 before quartz.net 3.x and the async direction it took. Since I am motivated to follow the general evolution to 3.x I am running into runtime issues to which I can't find a solution online.

Can someone please show me an example of how to schedule jobs in an asp.net 4.x global.asax application_start method making use of the quartz_jobs.xml file.

The runtime error I am getting is the following:
`System.InvalidOperationException:` 'Start may not be called on a task that has completed.'

The code that was ran:

```
Task<IScheduler> scheduler;
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  StdSchedulerFactory stdSchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
  scheduler = stdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
  scheduler.Start(); /* the line that is responsible for the runtime error */
}
```

I am aware of the objections of scheduling jobs under IIS but choose to do so after consideration so any example on how to avoid this error would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

`GetScheduler()` in Quartz 3 does not returns `IScheduler`. It returns `Task<IScheduler>`. It's a coincidence that both types, `Task` and `IScheduler`, have `Start()` method.

To convert `Task<IScheduler>` to `IScheduler` in a synchronous method like `Application_Start`, you first have to wait for the task to end and then get its result.

```
var realScheduler = scheduler.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
realScheduler.Start().Wait(); // you have to wait here too, because IScheduler.Start is also async
```